# Synonym for Sine Wave Half Cycle

Tags: mains, wave, terminology, sine

One cycle of a sine wave (such as the mains power voltage) consists of two half cycles (often called positive and negative in electronics).

Is there a (preferably one-word) term to refer to such a `sine wave half cycle`?

I have seen the term `half sine wave`, but it is hardly better. And besides, I believe this refers to all positive or all negative half cycles in aggregate, not to individual half cycles.

I am especially interested in this in regards to the mains power.

Comment: I'd call it a positive half cycle.

Comment: "Swing" sounds appropriate. Pity no one is using it :)

Comment: I think "positive half cycle" is good. Brainstorming alternatives: maybe "first pi"?

Comment: expanding on @EugeneSh. comment ... `upswing`

Answer (score 2):

As is often the case, it depends on context. If the entire waveform is present, but you you want to point out a particular half-cycle, you should say "positive half cycle" or negative half-cycle. If you have a zero-crossing switch that lets through a half cycle out of every 5 cycles then you have a series of "sinusoidal pulses" or a series of positive or negative "sinusoidal pulses." You might shorten that to "sine pulse."

Comment: +1 for sine pulse

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a aware of a specific term, but if you introduce it you can use you can invent your own terminology, eg "hump" "sinus" "pulse".

Answer (score 0):

I really like the sound of a `sine pulse` that @CharlesCowie suggested. Unfortunately, it seems a little ambiguous to me whether it refers to a half sine cycle or a full sine cycle.

I propose a `sine lobe`. It does not sound as good as the  `sine pulse` but I believe is less ambiguous.